# MaxScript create a a lot of files

Tags: maxscript, 3ds

The script creates a lot of files in a loop 
After starting the 3D max script can only create 499 files. Then displays the error "Runtime Error". 
Can I change this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it, is to create the files first by using the dos command feature.
For example:

```
HiddenDosCommand "mkdir c:\\NewDir\\"
HiddenDosCommand "type NUL > c:\\NewDir\\EmptyFile.txt"
```

will create a  new folder and a new empty file in that folder, you can then store the path to this file in a array.

Then in your loop you point to the path through the array of file paths, and insert your data into each file.